# SOQL - Left Join on a table with itself

Tags: soql

I have a tabular representation of a directed acyclic graph. The table has two columns, one for the node and the other for the dependent node.

For example, If I have 3 nodes `A`, `B` and `C` as follows:

```
A      B
 \    /
  \  /
   C
```

My dependency graph in Salesforce would be

```
C -> A
C -> B
A -> null
B -> null
```

Now, I believe the right way to convert this into an adjacency list would be to perform a left join on this table with itself, resulting in

```
A -> C
B -> C
C -> null
```

My table has the structure Dependency_Graph__c(Node__c, Dependent_Node__c). How would I be able to perform this operation SOQL? I am aware that doing self-joins in Salesforce is not possible. Is there a workaround of sorts?

Thanks!

Comment: What is it exactly you are trying to retrieve? `B` records joined to a specific `A`?  `C` records with data from `A` and `B`? Something else entirely?

Comment: @AdrianLarson C records with data from A and B. 
If you imagine the DAG I've shown in the examples, there can be two ways of representing it in memory. One way is to model child : parent (dependencies) and the other way is to model parent : child (adjacencies). My problem is, given the former, I want to get the latter. I figured out that what I need is a self left join of column 1 with column 2, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Just at a high level, though, what are you actually trying to achieve? It seems like you just want to pull in parent data via [`Right Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Right_Outer_Join)?

Comment: @AdrianLarson now I'm confused as to what Join it is, but it looks like that's what I need.

I don't really have a technical way of describing what I want to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pull in data from both parent records, consider a [`Right Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Right_Outer_Join).

An example of what it might look like:

```
for (C__c commonChild : [SELECT A__r.Name, B__r.Name FROM C__c WHERE ...])
{
    A__c parentA = commonChild.A__r;
    B__c parentB = commonChild.B__r;
}
```

You can pull in more fields from either parent in this way.

Note from [SOQL and SOSL Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_soslsoql.htm) that you can only include 35 such fields in one query:

> **Feature**
>   Relationship queries
>
> **Limit**
>   Relationship query limits
>
> **Limit Description**
>
> - No more than 35 child-to-parent relationships can be specified in a query. A custom object allows up to 25 relationships, so you can reference all the child-to-parent relationships for a custom object in one query.
> - No more than 20 parent-to-child relationships can be specified in a query.
> - In each specified relationship, no more than five levels can be specified in a child-to-parent relationship. For example, Contact.Account.Owner.FirstName (three levels).
> - In each specified relationship, only one level of parent-to-child relationship can be specified in a query. For example, if the FROM clause specifies Account, the SELECT clause can specify only the Contact or other objects at that level. It could not specify a child object of Contact.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Am having a little trouble wrapping my head around this solution. What would go in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Any filters you want. You could filter on parent fields using a `Right Inner Join`, for example.

Comment: Cool, just tried this in my application and it works. Thanks.